# How to get headers and data from createAsyncThunk axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

There is a `createAsyncThunk` in which I use `axios` to make a request. If I do `return res`, and I pass `action.payload.data` to my pizzas array, then everything works, but I get an error in the console:

http://joxi.ru/eAO8VK3CvyXqwr

I understand what needs to be done (`return res.data`) and then there will be no error.

But I need something to be returned `return res`, because I need to get `res.headers["x-total-count"]` from the request elsewhere and pass the quantity to `itemsCount`

```js
export const fetchPizzas = createAsyncThunk("items/fetchPizzasStatus", async (params) => {
  const { category, sortBy, order, search, perPage, currentPage } = params;
  const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/items?${category}&q=${search}&_sort=${sortBy}&_order=${order}&_page=${currentPage}&_limit=${perPage}`);
  return res;
});

const initialState = {
  pizzas: [],
  itemsCount: 0,
  status: "loading",
};

export const getItemsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "items",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchPizzas.pending]: (state) => {
      state.status = "loading";
      state.pizzas = [];
    },
    [fetchPizzas.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "success";
      state.pizzas = action.payload.data;
      state.itemsCount = action.payload.headers["x-total-count"];
    },
    [fetchPizzas.rejected]: (state) => {
      state.status = "error";
      state.pizzas = [];
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the API is configured to allow access to all the response headers then I'd suggest unpacking the header value you want/need in the action creator prior to returning a resolved value. The error is that something in the headers object is non-serializable, i.e. like a function.

Example:

```js
export const fetchPizzas = createAsyncThunk(
  "items/fetchPizzasStatus",
  async ({ category, sortBy, order, search, perPage, currentPage }) => {
    const { data, headers } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/items?${category}&q=${search}&_sort=${sortBy}&_order=${order}&_page=${currentPage}&_limit=${perPage}`);

    const itemCount = headers["x-total-count"];

    return { data, itemCount };
  }
);
```

```js
const initialState = {
  pizzas: [],
  itemsCount: 0,
  status: "loading",
};

export const getItemsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "items",
  initialState,
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchPizzas.pending]: (state) => {
      state.status = "loading";
      state.pizzas = [];
    },
    [fetchPizzas.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "success";
      state.pizzas = action.payload.data;
      state.itemsCount = action.payload.itemCount;
    },
    [fetchPizzas.rejected]: (state) => {
      state.status = "error";
      state.pizzas = [];
    },
  },
});
```

This said, it seems like the `itemCount` state is simply the length of the `pizzas` array and is easily derived from the existing state. It very likely doesn't need to also be stored in state. I'd recommend just completely removing it.

```js
export const fetchPizzas = createAsyncThunk(
  "items/fetchPizzasStatus",
  async ({ category, sortBy, order, search, perPage, currentPage }) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/items?${category}&q=${search}&_sort=${sortBy}&_order=${order}&_page=${currentPage}&_limit=${perPage}`);

    return data;
  }
);

const initialState = {
  pizzas: [],
  status: "loading",
};

export const getItemsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "items",
  initialState,
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchPizzas.pending]: (state) => {
      state.status = "loading";
      state.pizzas = [];
    },
    [fetchPizzas.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.status = "success";
      state.pizzas = action.payload;
    },
    [fetchPizzas.rejected]: (state) => {
      state.status = "error";
      state.pizzas = [];
    },
  },
});
```

```js
const pizzas = useSelector(state => state.items.pizzas);
const itemCount = useSelector(state => state.items.pizzas.length);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped a lot, because I thought for a long time how to do it!